# Is the JsonSerializerSettings thread safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, json.net

If I use the same settings across my project, can I instantiate a single static copy of my `JsonSerializerSettings` and use that throughout?

For example :

```
private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
    Formatting              = Formatting.Indented,
    TypeNameHandling        = TypeNameHandling.None,
    DateFormatHandling      = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
    TypeNameAssemblyFormat  = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple
};

public static string ToJSONString(this Object source) {
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source, settings);
}
```

So, am i thread *dangerous*?

Comment: Is there really any measurable performance gain in having the settings static?

Comment: Do you mutate `JsonSerializerSettings` anywhere in your program? I mean change its properties anywhere?

Comment: I understand what you mean by mutate.  No - set once at app startup.  Made the static var "readonly" to make intention clear.

Comment: @UweKeim -- I can't say -- i would have to measure.  This isn't a question about performance, for me at least.

Comment: So when it is no performance question, simply make `settings` not a static member but a local variable in `ToJSONString` and all possible threading issues are gone :-)

Comment: @UweKeim - you're assuming there aren't other reasons to code it this way.  Even if you disagree, I went to look if the class is thread safe and couldn't find the information anywhere.  Now the information exists for others.

Comment: If you aren't telling the "other reasons", how would you expect a decent answer?

Comment: I'm not asking *how* I should design a snippet of software.  My other reasons are irrelevant and too localized to be of relevance to the community. I'm asking if the object is thread safe. The answer to that question is factual. How I should design my software is opinion based, and more properly asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Could you find out if it is thread safe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following conversation happened on twitter, @JamesNK being the author of JSON.net: https://twitter.com/jonathan_oliver/status/332227095616966656

> From: Jonathan Oliver ‏@jonathan_oliver To: @JamesNK
>
> Are the static JsonConvert.DeserializeObject methods thread safe? Getting some strange errors using 5.0.4 and 5.0.5.

Response:

> James Newton-King ♔ ‏@JamesNK  8 May 2013 @jonathan_oliver
>
> Yes. Create an issue on GitHub if they’re not

Response:

> Jonathan Oliver ‏@jonathan_oliver  9 May 2013
>
> @JamesNK It turns out a ContractResolver attached to a static JsonSerializerSettings object I used with JsonConvert wasn't thread safe.

I do not see that a bug was ever filed, but this does hint that the design of them is supposed to be thread safe, but there maybe implementation specific ways to ruin that or it might not be as a whole.

Answer (score 3):

Since you say you don't mutate `JsonSerializerSettings` there is no need to worry about thread safety. Thread race can happen only when modifying the shared data in another thread but that is not the case here.

I suggest you to read [this article](http://www.albahari.com/threading/), in the end you should have a good understanding of threads, thread safety etc.

Also Thread safety is a more general term, you need to be more precise what you meant by that. Refer [What is this thing you call "thread safe"?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx) for more info.

Comment: That's a brave assumption that `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` is thread-safe on the second parameter. How do you know? Did you read the documentation or look at the source code?

Comment: Fair enough on my loose language and funny enough I've read that article before.  My question wasn't really about the concept generally, but instead the risks @UweKeim points out -- I have no idea what Json.net does with the settings internally.

Comment: @UweKeim What makes second parameter not thread safe? Setting some properties in a object and reading in multiple threads are meant to be thread safe unless those properties are computed and returned. This is a intuitive assumption that `SerializeObject` should ever mutate the settings passed in. btw this raises the question how do you believe this is not threadsafe? We can't answer unless we look in to source.